# Как реализовать увеличение змейки?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый вечер. 
Я продолжаю писать змейку без использования canvas, игра почти готова, но осталось реализовать довольно сложный процесс - увеличение змейки при поедании яблока. Здесь же возник вопрос, как это реализовать, пока что вообще никаких идей по этому поводу нету.
В коде по максимуму попытался объяснить что за что отвечает, заранее спасибо за подкинутые идеи, возможно готовые решения.
Строго не судите, я еще не профи в Js)
Вот и сам код: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ANTON_ZIN_/pen/OqgJZy)

```js
var mainBlock = document.getElementById("mainBlock"), // Игровая область
    snakeBlock = document.getElementById("snakeBlock"), // Змейка(белый квадрат)
    appleBlock = document.getElementById("appleBlock"), // Яблоко(черный квадрат)
    scoreBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("scoreBlock")[0], // Блок очков
    score = document.getElementById("score"), // Набранные очки
    scoreValue = Number(score.innerHTML), // Отображение набранных очков
    playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn"), // Кнопка PLAY
    myConfirm = document.getElementById("myConfirm"), // Свое окно Confirm
    okeyBtn = document.getElementById("agree"), // Кнопка OK(PLAY в confirm)
    exitBtn = document.getElementById("desagree"), // Кнопка EXIT
    snakeX = mainBlock.offsetWidth/2 - 10, // Начальные координаты змейки по X, центр
    snakeY = mainBlock.offsetHeight/2 - 10, // Начальные координаты змейки по Y, центр
    appleX, appleY, // Координаты яблока(зададим позже)
    t, // Переменная для будущей установки/сброса setInterval
    activeGame = false, // Игра не запущена по умолчанию
    eatCost = 10, // Стоимость одного яблока
    maxX = mainBlock.clientWidth - 20, // 20px - ширина головы змейки
    maxY = mainBlock.clientHeight - 20; // 20px - высота головы змейки


function moveUp() {
    if (snakeX > 0) {
        snakeX -= 20;
        snakeBlock.style.top = snakeX + "px";
        eat();
    } else {
        myConfirmDisplay();
    }
}

function moveDown() {
    if (snakeX < maxY) {
        snakeX += 20;
        snakeBlock.style.top = snakeX + "px";
        eat();
    } else {
        myConfirmDisplay();
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    if (snakeY > 0) {
        snakeY -= 20;
        snakeBlock.style.left = snakeY + "px";
        eat();
    } else {
        myConfirmDisplay();
    }
}

function moveRight() {
    if (snakeY < maxX) {
        snakeY += 20;
        snakeBlock.style.left = snakeY + "px";
        eat();
    } else {
        myConfirmDisplay();
    }
}

playBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {

    activeGame = true;

    createEat();
    resetParams();

    playBtn.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие кнопки PLAY
    snakeBlock.style.display = 'block'; // Отображение змейки
    scoreBlock.style.display = 'block'; // Отображение очков

    var activeArr; // Переменная для отслеживания направления и запрета двигатся в противоположную сторону, true - если кубик двигается вверх/вниз, false - если влево/вправо

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37 && activeArr !== false) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = setInterval(moveLeft, 50);
            activeArr = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 38 && activeArr !== true) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = setInterval(moveUp, 50);
            activeArr = true;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 39 && activeArr !== false) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = setInterval(moveRight, 50);
            activeArr = false;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 40 && activeArr !== true) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = setInterval(moveDown, 50);
            activeArr = true;
        }
    });
}

function resetParams() {
    snakeX = mainBlock.offsetWidth/2 - 10,
    snakeY = mainBlock.offsetHeight/2 - 10,
    snakeBlock.style.top = snakeX + 'px';
    snakeBlock.style.left = snakeY + 'px';

    if (t !== undefined){
        clearInterval(t);
    }

    score.innerHTML = 0;
    scoreValue = Number(score.innerHTML);
}

function myConfirmDisplay(){
    activeGame = false;
    myConfirm.style.display = 'flex';
    snakeBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие змейки
    appleBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие яблока
    scoreBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие очков
    okeyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        startGame();
        myConfirm.style.display = 'none';
    });
    exitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        playBtn.style.display = 'block'; // Отображение кнопки PLAY
        snakeBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие змейки
        scoreBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие очков
        myConfirm.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие окна выбора
        resetParams();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && activeGame == false) {
            startGame();
            myConfirm.style.display = 'none';
        } else if (e.keyCode == 27 && activeGame == false) {
            playBtn.style.display = 'block'; // Отображение кнопки PLAY
            snakeBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие змейки
            scoreBlock.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие очков
            myConfirm.style.display = 'none'; // Скрытие окна выбора
            resetParams();
        }
    });
}

function createEat(){
    appleBlock.style.display = 'block';

    appleX = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*(500 + 1)) / 20) * 20;
    appleY = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*(500 + 1)) / 20) * 20; // Координаты яблока(промежуток от 0 до 500(ширина и высота игровой области))

    appleBlock.style.top = appleX + 'px';
    appleBlock.style.left = appleY + 'px';
}

function eat() {
    if(snakeX == appleX && snakeY == appleY){
        scoreValue += eatCost;
        score.innerHTML = scoreValue;
        appleBlock.style.display = 'none';
        createEat();
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainBlock {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 2px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 36px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#playBtn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    outline: none;
}
#playBtn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#snakeBlock {
    display: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
}
#appleBlock {
    display: none;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}

#myConfirm {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 350px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    
}
.main-text {
    text-align: center;
}
.header {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#agree,
#desagree {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    outline: none;

}
#agree:hover,
#desagree:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scoreBlock {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 93%;
    left: 20%;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#score {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="myConfirm">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="main-text">
                <div class="head-text">
                    <h4 class="header">Play again?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="desc-text">
                    <input id="agree" type="button" value="PLAY">
                    <input id="desagree" type="button" value="EXIT">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mainBlock">
        <input id="playBtn" type="button" value="PLAY">
        <div id="snakeBlock"></div>

        <div id="appleBlock"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scoreBlock">
        Score:
        <span id="score">0</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Правильно перемещение змейки:**
- за 1 тик: убирается последний элемент змейки, добавляется впереди.
- когда змейка сьедает что-то, последний элемент просто не убирается.
Поэтому нужно реализовать правильный алгоритм перемещения для начала.

Comment: Хорошо, саму суть примерно понял, теперь нужно рассмотреть это подробнее. Ее же нужно добавлять конкретно с противоположной стороны от направления самой змейки, при этом чтобы этот элемент имел все те же свойства и вел себя так как и голова змеки. Ну икак я понял их как-то в массиве хранить, или нет необходимости?

Comment: Если у вас не нарисованы голова и хвост, то без разницы с какой стороны добавлять.

Comment: Ну почему без разницы, если я съел в горизонтальном направлении, а добавилось сверху, тогда змейка будет двигаться боком, до нажатия клавиши клавы

Comment: вопрос уже решён?